# The evolution of airline safety videos - is it going in the wrong direction?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, airlines

When the very first airline safety videos were introduced, they were very straight-forward, explaining the features of the aircraft without any extra drama / cultural element infused in them.

[Over the years, airlines realised that passengers were not paying attention to the safety videos and decided to change the safety videos. That change was to infuse an element of culture of the country which the airline represents (in the case of a flag carrier) / it hails from. Some changes were also to infuse entertainment.](https://www.aerotime.aero/articles/eight-of-the-most-unforgettable-inflight-safety-videos-of-all-time)

---

Air New Zealand first started this trend (or so it is said to have started this trend) with the 'Lord of the Rings - The Hobbit' safety video. Many other airlines followed suit - the most recent being Air India with its video based on Indian classical dances. Singapore Airlines (sights of Singapore), Qatar Airways (football theme), British Airways (that comedy) are many other examples.

But there are lot of concerns surrounding this. [A study](https://%20https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279312801_Pre-flight_safety_briefings_mood_and_information_retention) has shown that straightforward safety videos are retained more than their more entertaining counterparts. Also, there are risks that the passengers might 'lose the details in the distractions'.

As quoted in the study:

> Tehrani and Molesworth (2015) contend that there are added advantages to improving the quality of the safety briefing on aircraft. Apart from the obvious improvements in knowledge, providing a briefing that carefully incorporates humour can positively impact on passengers' mood, which in turn can translate into improved performance (i.e., during an emergency evacuation). However, Smith (1993) offers a word of caution when using humour in advertising. He contends that humour can disrupt the systematic processing of target/advertising material/information, resulting in the target message being lost to the humorous message. Chan (2011) found that indeed humour can disrupt the processing of the target message in a study with 253 university student and five different advertisements (two humorous, two non-humorous and one neutral). Moreover, while the humorous advertisements were more successful in gaining the attention of the students, they were found to cause more disruptions during the processing of the message.

**Are we going in the right direction with regard to this? Please give either yes / no + a justification for the same.**

---

**Citations:**

Tehrani, Morteza & Molesworth, Brett. (2015). Pre-flight safety briefings, mood and information retention. Applied Ergonomics. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apergo.2015.06.015

Comment: If that study actually exists it will not be hard to find... a very good question though!

Comment: I suspect it is this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279312801_Pre-flight_safety_briefings_mood_and_information_retention

Comment: Yes @Jamiec! Thank you! I was hunting for this. I couldn't find it anywhere else once I saw it (I guess I should be blaming Google algorithms).

Comment: I've requested the full text and will craft an answer if I get it

Comment: Obviously, some people think this is going in the _right_ direction, others may consider it going in the _wrong_ direction. As written, this is an opinion based question.